# Summation involving digamma and floor functions

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics

I am trying to find an asymptotic expansion for the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^K \frac{\phi_0( 1/2+n+\lfloor(2n-1)/\sqrt{2}\rfloor)}{(4n-2)}$$

where $\phi_0$ is the digamma function and $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$.
I found that, when $K$ tends to $\infty$, the result is

$$\displaystyle (\log^2{K})/8+\log(1+\sqrt{2}) (\log{K})/4+ 0.031914...$$

I would be very interested in knowing whether  this constant term can be expressed in some other ways. I am not  necessarily searching a strictly closed form, but rather a more elegant way to report it (e.g. as a function).

Comment: Should the upper limit of the summation be $K$?  Also, how did you arrive at your result?

Comment: Yes, the upper limit is $K$. I edited the question to better specify this. I found the asymptotic formula empirically. Accordingly, I would also be interested about the way to prove it.